# Ajax updatet score from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to create a form with three "Likert Scale" input.
For all three input field there is totaly 10 points that can be devided on the three "Likert scale" inputs. When this score is equal to 0, the submit button should be enabled and the form can be submitted. The number of points left should be updated without having the page reloade using ajax, so the user will know how many points that are left.

I have not really figured out how to do this but I have added some pseudo code, to explain this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  // Initial score/points
  var score = 10;
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;

  $('input:radio').click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    // update score, based on clicked alternative value
    new_score = score - alternative_clicked;
    if new_score < 0:
      var error = "You do not have enoght points left, choose a smaler number";

    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = error;

    else if new_score === 0:
      // enable submit button

      else :
        // update score with new_score value
  });

  $('input:submit').click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();

    // send to google spreadsheet

  });

});
```

```css
table.striped-columns tbody td:nth-of-type(even),
table.striped-columns th:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: blue;
}

table.striped-columns tbody td:nth-of-type(odd),
table.striped-columns th:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #fafafa;
}

table.border {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table.border td,
table.border th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This should be updated  -->
<p><b>TOTAL POINTS LEFT:</b> <span id="score"></span></p>

<form method="post" action="/echo/html/" ajax="true">

  <table class="striped-columns border">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>TEST</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alternativ 1</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="alternativ1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="2" name="alternativ1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="3" name="alternativ1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="4" name="alternativ1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="5" name="alternativ1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alternativ 2</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="alternativ2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="2" name="alternativ2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="3" name="alternativ2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="4" name="alternativ2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="5" name="alternativ2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alternativ 3</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="alternativ3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="2" name="alternativ3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="3" name="alternativ3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="4" name="alternativ3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="5" name="alternativ3" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one way to do that:

***(sorry for bad indentation in the snippet. Seems it is a bit [buggy feature in SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345600/stack-snippet-indentation-preview-differs-from-result))***

I use `eval()` so I wouldn't need to write many if/else statements.

However - [eval() isn’t evil, just misunderstood](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  // Initial score/points
  var score = 10;
  var a1 = 0, a2 = 0, a3 = 0;
  
  var inputs = $('input');
  
  inputs.each(function(i) {
   $(this).on('click', function() {     
     var clicked = $(this).closest('tr').get(0).id;
      
      score += eval(clicked)      
      score -= eval(clicked + " = " + $(this).val());
      
    $("#score").html(score);
      
      if (score == 0 && (a1 != 0 && a2 != 0 && a3 != 0)) {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
      } else {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```css
table.striped-columns tbody td:nth-of-type(even),
table.striped-columns th:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: blue;
}

table.striped-columns tbody td:nth-of-type(odd),
table.striped-columns th:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #fafafa;
}

table.border {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table.border td,
table.border th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="/echo/html/" ajax="true">

  <table class="striped-columns border">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>TEST</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="a1">
        <td>Alternativ 1</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="alternativ1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="2" name="alternativ1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="3" name="alternativ1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="4" name="alternativ1" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="5" name="alternativ1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="a2">
        <td>Alternativ 2</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="alternativ2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="2" name="alternativ2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="3" name="alternativ2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="4" name="alternativ2" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="5" name="alternativ2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="a3">
        <td>Alternativ 3</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="alternativ3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="2" name="alternativ3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="3" name="alternativ3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="4" name="alternativ3" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="5" name="alternativ3" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled/>
  <div id="score">  10
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Oh, and no need for AJAX here because you are not pulling any data from database, AFAIK